# Replace string with another string plus respective position

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, oracle11g, oracle12c

I wonder if it is possible to replace specific string with another string plus position without using PL/SQL block (loops, user defined function/stored procedures, with function construct ...).

Here: `st` -> `pos_num`

Input:

```
"aa bbb st cccc dddd st eeeeeeeeeee ffff g st g h i st j k l m st"
```

Output:

```
"aa bbb pos_1 cccc dddd pos_2 eeeeeeeeeee ffff g pos_3 g h i pos_4 j k l m pos_5"
```

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=28fe7e2453355dc2f60ad6f91cb57859)**

I feel that it is possible to achieve it with one line operation(maybe regex).

Comment: Yes . may be with `REGEXP_INSTR` , `REGEXP_REPLACE` and `LEVEL` combination.?

Comment: is a recursive cte ok? or you prefer only a one liner :) ?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Feel free to post your solution :) One line elegant solution  is preferred but not necessary  :)

Comment: Do you need to replace the string even if it is within a longer word? So, in your example, do you replace the input string `'post'` with `'popos_1'`? If not - if 'st' is only replaced if it is a "stand-alone word", what are the rules? (For example: what if it's part of a compound word, like `'st-jack'`?)

Comment: @mathguy Only full word so `st-jack` should not be affected. `<space>st<space>` should be replaced.

Comment: ...and (from your example) the beginning of the string and the end of the string count as "spaces". Then punctuation doesn't count as spaces. One difficulty is with <space>st<space>st<space>, because Oracle regular expressions don't have the concept of "look-back" or whatever it's called. Once a space is used to find the first pattern, it can't be used to recognize the second pattern in the same pass (it can't be used to match TWO patterns).

Comment: @mathguy So let's assume that there will be always between `st <anything> st`. There will be no `st st`.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Regexp_REPLACE with MODEL do the job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MODEL` clause:

```
select m_1
from dual
model dimension by (0 as key)
measures (cast('st post aa bbb st cccc dddd st ee ffff g st g h i st j k l m st' 
                as varchar2(500)) as m_1 )
rules iterate (100) until(not regexp_like(m_1[0], '( |^)(st)( |$)'))
(m_1[0] = regexp_replace(m_1[0],
          '( |^)st( |$)','\1pos_'||to_char(ITERATION_NUMBER+1)||'\2',1,1));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=45b5b4732081fa881d106bd1e18e8e26)**

Output:

```
pos_1 post aa bbb pos_2 cccc dddd pos_3 ee ffff g pos_4 g h i pos_5 j k l m pos_6
```

Comment: If you are interested in performance, you may still want to try this both ways. The `model` clause is notoriously slow; but (1) perhaps you don't have a lot of data, so you don't care; and (2) in any case, the only way to know for sure is by testing on **your** data, not someone else's.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive cte approach.

```
with cte(string,col,cnt,repl) as
(select string,1,regexp_count(string,'st'),regexp_replace(string,'st','pos_'||to_char(1),1,1) as repl
 from test
 union all
 select string,col+1,cnt,regexp_replace(repl,'st','pos_'||to_char(col+1),1,1) as repl
 from cte
 --join it to the original table if there are multiple rows, on string column.
 where col<cnt
)
cycle col set cycle to 1 default 0
select string,repl
from cte
where cnt=col
```

Comment: +1 The solution is essentially correct. The recursive CTE results in a cycle violation, which can be cured by adding a CYCLE clause to the recursive CTE. Also, there is no need to use the "count" to cut off the recursion; I show one way to do that in my Answer. But overall the solution is good. I will edit the answer to add the CYCLE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different solution using recursive CTE. It looks for `st` only when it is surrounded by spaces (or by beginning or end of string).

```
with
  inputs ( str ) as (
    select 'aa bbb st sccc dddd st eee fff g st g h i st j k l m st' from dual
    union all
    select 'st abc st st st where st is not st'                      from dual
    union all
    select 'post st stop postal'                                     from dual
  ),
  r ( lvl, str, new_str ) as (
    select  1, str, str
      from  inputs
    union all
    select  lvl + 1, str, 
            regexp_replace(new_str, '( |^)st( |$)', '\1pos_' || lvl || '\2', 1, 1)
      from  r
      where regexp_like(new_str, '( |^)(st)( |$)')
  )
select str, new_str
from   r
where  not regexp_like(new_str, '( |^)(st)( |$)')
;

STR                                                      NEW_STR
-------------------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
post st stop postal                                      post pos_1 stop postal
aa bbb st sccc dddd st eee fff g st g h i st j k l m st  aa bbb pos_1 sccc dddd pos_2 eee fff g pos_3 g h i pos_4 j k l m pos_5
st abc st st st where st is not st                       pos_1 abc pos_2 pos_3 pos_4 where pos_5 is not pos_6
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Combining it with `MODEL` works very well :)